# Link with image hover - Need help positioning image

Tags: css

**Issue:**
I have a responsive design and a 2 column set of links. Each set of links is a list. They are aligned center. When you hover there is an arrow that is supposed to appear next to the text, but I'm having trouble fluidly positioning it. The best I've come up with absolutely positioning the arrow on hover so it "works" with all of the my list items. It looks like crap though. I'd like it to be to the left of each of the h3 in each list. I just haven't figured out a clever way of doing it.

```
<div class="contentLeft">
        <ul class="ca-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h3 class="ca-main"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/arrow-hover.jpg" class="arrow" width="61" height="29" alt="Arrow Hover">This is the link</h3>
                        <p class="ca-sub">This is the subheading</p>
                    </div>  
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h3 class="ca-main"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/arrow-hover.jpg" class="arrow" width="61" height="29" alt="Arrow Hover">This is the link</h3>
                        <p class="ca-sub">This is the subheading</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h3 class="ca-main"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/arrow-hover.jpg" class="arrow" width="61" height="29" alt="Arrow Hover">This is the link</h3>
                        <p class="ca-sub">This is the subheading</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h3 class="ca-main"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/arrow-hover.jpg" class="arrow" width="61" height="29" alt="Arrow Hover">This is the link</h3>
                        <p class="ca-sub">This is the subheading</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="contentRight">
        <ul class="ca-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h3 class="ca-main"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/arrow-hover.jpg" class="arrow" width="61" height="29" alt="Arrow Hover">This is the link</h3>
                        <p class="ca-sub">This is the subheading</p>
                    </div>  
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h3 class="ca-main"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/arrow-hover.jpg" class="arrow" width="61" height="29" alt="Arrow Hover">This is the link</h3>
                        <p class="ca-sub">This is the subheading</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h3 class="ca-main"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/arrow-hover.jpg" class="arrow" width="61" height="29" alt="Arrow Hover">This is the link</h3>
                        <p class="ca-sub">This is the subheading</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="ca-content">
                        <h3 class="ca-main"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/arrow-hover.jpg" class="arrow" width="61" height="29" alt="Arrow Hover">This is the link</h3>
                        <p class="ca-sub">This is the subheading</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
    .arrow {
  display: none;
  width: 61px;
     }
.ca-menu li:hover .arrow {
  display: inline;
  width: 61px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;

}
.ca-menu {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.ca-menu li {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-menu li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.ca-menu li a {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.ca-content {
  height: 60px;
}
.ca-main {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 29px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-sub {
  color: #999 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon {
  color: #e3721e;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 13px #fff;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #e3721e;
  -webkit-animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: moveFromTop 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease-in-out;
  color: #333 !important;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: post a jsfiddle next time. Makes people want to help if its easy to see. heres the jsfiddle for this one: http://jsfiddle.net/x2qE9/
I guess you'll need to make your image attached via an image hosting site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix for this is a -ve margin. ***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/x2qE9/1/)*** is a working Live Demo. But you have to consider some things. If you assign height and width to your image, if that is not changing, and if you have already set it in your CSS, you need not put it along with `<img>`. Simply define image width and height in your CSS.

Comment: @Ilan Biala Thanks for the jfiddle. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: That did it. That's exactly the behavior I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

started a jsfiddle to begin work on this because it definitely deserves attention. Now I'm not sure if i got what you wanted right, but I'm positive this needs some more work. I got the starting format and arrow appearance down, but to activate both you need to hover particularly over the word "the" in the link and slide your mouse up a little. I'm going to keep working on that problem so that you can actually use what I have provided but let me know if there is anything else you would want differently.

Here's the fiddle: [jsfiddle linked here :)](http://jsfiddle.net/gwSaC/3/)